# Proving that a measure equals the spherical measure on $\Bbb S^{n-1}$: namely, $\mu= |\Bbb S^{n-2}|\sigma_{n-1}$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, spheres, geometric-measure-theory

Let $n\ge 3$ and $\Bbb S^{n-1}$ denote the $n-1$-dimensional unit sphere in $\Bbb R^{n}$ namely, $\Bbb S^{n-1}= \{x \in \Bbb R^{n}: \|x\|=1\}$

For $v\in \Bbb S^{n-1}$ fixed we define 
$$\Bbb S_v^{n-2}=\Bbb S^{n-1}\cap (\Bbb R v)^\bot$$ where $(\Bbb R v)^\bot$ is the orthogonal of $v$ in $\Bbb R^{n}$.  For $A\subset \Bbb S^{n-1}$
$$\mu(A)= \int_{\Bbb S^{n-1}}\mathcal{H}^{n-2}(A\cap\Bbb S_v^{n-2})d\sigma_{n-1}(v) $$
where $d\sigma_{n-1}$ represent the Lebesgue surface measure on $\Bbb S^{n-1}$ and $\mathcal{H}^{n-2}$ is the the $n-2$-Hausdorff measure.

**Question:** How can one prove that
$$\mu= |\Bbb S^{n-2}|\mathcal{H}^{n-1}¬\Bbb S_v^{n-1}:= |\Bbb S^{n-2}|\sigma_{n-1}$$

For further information also see this:[How to prove that : $\mathcal{H}^{n-2}(\Bbb S_v^{n-2})=|\Bbb S^{n-2}|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2582916/how-to-prove-that-mathcalhn-2-bbb-s-vn-2-bbb-sn-2)

Comment: So this is also from the page 7 that you have told me. But I think the proof is problematic, at least, the reasoning should not be like that: what I can see is that, the author seems to use the fact that up to constant multiple, there is only one Haar measure. But only ${\bf{S}}^{0}$, ${\bf{S}}^{1}$, and ${\bf{S}}^{3}$ are spheres which can be endowed with topological groups.

Comment: My second guess is that, maybe we define $\mu$ to be a Borel measure on ${\bf{R}}^{n}$? And endow the ${\bf{R}}^{n}$ to be the topological group as the natural one. But then I cannot see why $\mu(A+x)=\mu(A)$. Meanwhile, no matter what, it is difficult to see also that why $\mu$ is a Radon measure. If it were failing to show that $\mu$ is Radon, then much less anything about Haar Theorem can be applied.