# Proving: $\int_{S^{n-1}}f(x)d\sigma_{n-1}(x)= \int_{\Bbb S^{n-1}}\int_{\Bbb S_v^{n-2}}f(y)\frac{d\sigma_{n-2}(y)}{|\Bbb S^{n-2}|}d\sigma_{n-1}(v) $

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, spheres, geometric-measure-theory

Let $n\ge 3$ and $\Bbb S^{n-1}$ denote the $n-1$-dimensional unit sphere in $\Bbb R^{n}$ namely, $\Bbb S^{n-1}= \{x \in \Bbb R^{n}: \|x\|=1\}$

For $v\in \Bbb S^{n-1}$ fixed we define 
$$\Bbb S_v^{n-2}=\Bbb S^{n-1}\cap (\Bbb R v)^\bot$$ where $(\Bbb R v)^\bot$ is the orthogonal of $v$ in $\Bbb R^{n}$.

**Question:** Let $f:\Bbb S^{n-1}\to \Bbb R$ be a measurable function. How  to prove that
 $$\int_{\Bbb S^{n-1}}f(x)d\sigma_{n-1}(x)= \int_{\Bbb S^{n-1}}\left(\int_{\Bbb S_v^{n-2}}f(y)\frac{d\sigma_{n-2}(y)}{|\Bbb S^{n-2}|}\right)d\sigma_{n-1}(v) $$
where $d\sigma_{n-1}$ represent the Lebesgue surface measure on $\Bbb S^{n-1}.$

Can anyone help?

For further information also see this:[How to prove that : $\mathcal{H}^{n-2}(\Bbb S_v^{n-2})=|\Bbb S^{n-2}|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2582916/how-to-prove-that-mathcalhn-2-bbb-s-vn-2-bbb-sn-2)

Comment: Any reference to this issue? The book Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions by Evans, I don't see it.

Comment: @user284331 I found this from the article by Augusto Ponce on: An estimate in the spirit of Poincaré's inequality page 7.

Comment: Actually I found a book regarding this formula (almost identical, so I believe in that way, it can prove your result), but I don't quite clear what it is going on with that reasoning. By the way, do you know any book on this issue? I mean, the integration on surface. Differential geometry books do not talk so much about this.

Comment: @user284331  although I don't understand why people chose to down vote this question, I dont have any good book at hand at the moment in the article it seemed to be trivial. But my guess would be to start searching on the side of references including stuff like  Haar measure.

Comment: I have put upvote to your question because I think this is interesting (I am not the downvoter). I will dig into the details of the reasoning that I do not understand and I will put the answer if I could.

Comment: @user284331 cool I have put it in stand by now. I spent too much understand mixure of geometry and measure theory this is new for me by the way.  you may also see a related question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2582916/how-to-prove-that-mathcalhn-2-bbb-s-vn-2-bbb-sn-2?rq=1